# Selenium - How identify disabled field

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

[image]I want to get the data from disabled field. Here is the HTML:
This field is a drop down and i want to identify selected data from the that field. 
for e.g. field name is Exchange and selected data is "ABC". 
My question is how to identify the selected data from disabled field.

```
<"select class="form-control input-sm mandatory ng-untouched ng-pristine"name="Exchange" id="topupExchange0" disabled=""">  
Select <"/option">  
        <!--template bindings={}-->  
        <"option value="ABC"> ABC<"/option">  
        <"option value="CDE"> CDE<"/option">  
    <"/select">
```

How can I identify the disabled field?

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what you are trying to do with the field? Do you want to focus on it, read the option values or option text? Verify that it is disabled when it should be? Or are you just trying to select it (if so, you should be able to use `myElem = findElement(By.Id, "topupExchange0");`

Answer (score 2):

**As per new Edit of question please follow below steps:**

1. Check first there is **any `iframe` or not**. (I am believing there is an `iframe`).So switch to it and get element.

   ```
   WebElement iframeElement = driver.findElement(By.id("IF1"));
   //now use the switch command
   driver.switchTo().frame(iframeElement);
   ```

[Refer this link](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/handling-iframes-using-selenium-webdriver/)

2. Your script requirements are based on the **disabled element**, So write below line to find it.

   ```
   List<WebElement> lstOpt =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//option[@disabled="disabled"]"));
   System.out.println(lstOpt);
   ```

> Extra notes

- First **get list of select** which have `disabled` option in attribute.

  ```
  List<WebElement> lstEle =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='topupExchange0']"));
  ```
- Then **check the condition** like follow :

  ```
  if(lstEle.size()>0)
  {
   System.out.println("Disable list is found.");
  }
  ```
- Now you can use as per your requirements like **Get options, Print options, ignore it, stop execution etc.**

---

**Example of get options :**

```
List<WebElement> lstOpt =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='topupExchange0']/option"));
System.out.println(lstOpt);
```

**Note : Answer is in Java**

Please let me know If any query.

Comment: It didn't works for me.

Comment: Can you please send the exception ?

Comment: Another requirement is  for disabled text box .                                                                               <"input class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid mat-input-element" mdinput="" type="text" maxlength="15" id="schemeCode" placeholder="Code" aria-describedby=""">

Comment: i'm not stack trace developer. Enclosed screenshot for your reference. Can you give the code as per the HTML tag. Would be helpful for me.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Answer is updated. Please check.